# Angular non-idempotent method issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a basic understanding of Angular's digest cycle, but I'm confused as to why this particular method is executing multiple times.  Here is what is in my Controller:

```
initializePage();
    function initializePage() {
        var promise = getPageInfo();
        promise.then(function () {
            $scope.dataLoading = true;
        })
    };
    function getPageInfo() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(lwsService.getLWSpageinfo()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.company = data.ContractorInfo;
            $scope.img = base64ArrayBuffer($scope.company.imgCompanyLogo);
            $scope.incompleteInfo = data.IncompleteInfo;
            $scope.sections = data.QuestionSections;
            $scope.verifications = data.Verifications;
            $scope.subscriptions = data.SubscriptionInfo;
            $scope.user = data.UserInfo;
            $scope.ssqstatus = data.SSQStatus;
            $scope.ssqdetails = data.SSQDetail[0];
            $scope.completionInfo = data.CompletionInfo[0];
            $scope.states = data.States;
            $scope.countries = data.Countries
            $scope.completionInfo.dteDateSSQLastUpdated = convertDate($scope.completionInfo.dteDateSSQLastUpdated);
                  return deferred.promise;
    };
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app-="myModule" ng-controller="LWSCtrl">
<div cg-busy="waitopr"></div>
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Dashboard">
        <div ng-repeat="m in majors">
            <div ng-controller="LWSCtrl">
                <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
                    <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
                        <accordion-heading>
                            <div style="height:20px">
                                <span class="pull-left">{{m.MajorName}}</span><i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !status.open}"></i>
                            </div>
                        </accordion-heading>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table style="border:none; width:100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="border:none">
                                            <div class="newWidget">
                                                <div class="WidgetTitle" style="width:100%; color:white" ng-style="{'background-color': m.header.WidgetStateBackgroundColor}">{{m.header.WidgetTitleText}}</div>
                                                <div style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px">
                                                    <ul class="grid-wrap one-whole plain">
                                                        <li ng-repeat="item in m.items" class="grid-col one-quarter">
                                                            <div ng-switch="item.IsModuleWordingFixed">
                                                                <div ng-switch-when="false">
                                                                    <div ng-switch="item.vchGraphic">
                                                                        <div ng-switch-when="images/ContractorRankingWidget/green.png">
                                                                            <span style="display:inline-block; cursor:pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#scoreOverride" ng-value="scoredetails" ng-click="Override(scoredetails)" ng-model="score.details" class="dashboard-button-green">{{item.ModuleCurrentStateText}}</span><span style="display:inline-block; font-weight:bolder; vertical-align:middle"> &nbsp; &nbsp;{{item.ModuleHeaderText}}<br />&nbsp;</span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div ng-switch-when="images/ContractorRankingWidget/red.png">
                                                                            <span style="display:inline-block; cursor:pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#scoreOverride" ng-value="scoredetails" ng-click="Override(scoredetails)" ng-model="score.details" class=" dashboard-button-red">{{item.ModuleCurrentStateText}}</span><span style="display:inline-block; font-weight:bolder; vertical-align:middle"> &nbsp; &nbsp;{{item.ModuleHeaderText}}<br /></span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        <div ng-switch-when="images/ContractorRankingWidget/yellow.png">
                                                                            <span style="display:inline-block; cursor:pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#scoreOverride" ng-value="scoredetails" ng-click="Override(scoredetails)" ng-model="score.details" class="dashboard-button-yellow">{{item.ModuleCurrentStateText}}</span><span style="display:inline-block; font-weight:bolder; vertical-align:middle"> &nbsp; &nbsp;{{item.ModuleHeaderText}}<br /> &nbsp;</span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>

                                                                </div>
                                                                <div ng-switch-when="true">
                                                                    <span style="display:inline-block; cursor:pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moduleOverride" ng-value="item" ng-click="moduleOverride(item)"><img ng-src="~/{{item.vchGraphic}}" /></span><span style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle"> &nbsp; &nbsp;<span style="font-weight:bolder">{{item.ModuleHeaderText}}</span><br /> &nbsp; &nbsp;{{item.ModuleCalculatedStateText}}</span>
                                                                    <div>&nbsp;</div>

                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="border:none">
                                            <table style="border:none">
                                                <tr ng-repeat="text in m.Legend">
                                                    <td style="border:none" class="LegendImage" ng-style="{'background-color': text.BackGroundColor}">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td style="border:none; padding:3px">{{text.WidgetStateText}}<br /></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr style="border:none" ng-if="overridden || moduleoverridden">
                                                    <td style="border:none"><img src="~/Images/ContractorRankingWidget/override.png" /></td>
                                                    <td style="border:none">Override</td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </accordion-group>
                </accordion>
            </div>
        </div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="SSQ Information">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div ng-switch="expired">
                    <div ng-switch-when="true">
                        <span style="display:inline-block" class="calendar-background-red"><img src="~/Images/calendar_icon.png" /></span><span style="display:inline-block"><span style="font-weight:bold"> &nbsp; &nbsp; Subscription Expiration Date</span><br /> &nbsp; &nbsp; {{subscriptions.dteExpiresWithGracePeriod}}</span><span class="float-right"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-switch-when="false">
                        <span style="display:inline-block" class="calendar-background-green"><img src="~/Images/calendar_icon.png" /></span><span style="display:inline-block"><span style="font-weight:bold"> &nbsp; &nbsp; Subscription Expiration Date</span><br /> &nbsp; &nbsp;  {{subscriptions.dteExpiresWithGracePeriod}}</span><span class="float-right"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br /><br />
                <div style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">
                    <table style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color:#003a5d; color:white">
                                <th colspan="5">
                                    SSQ Status
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="background-color:#b4001a; color:white">
                                <th colspan="5">
                                    <div ng-switch="ssqstatus">
                                        <div ng-switch-when="false">
                                            Incomplete
                                        </div>
                                        <div ng-switch-when="true">
                                            Complete
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="background-color:#cfe7f1; text-align:center">
                                <th>SSQ Last Edited By</th>
                                <th style="text-align:center">Date Edited</th>
                                <th style="text-align:center">Last Incident QTR Reported</th>
                                <th style="text-align:center">Number of Employees</th>
                                <th style="text-align:center">Number of Active Instructors</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{completionInfo.CompletedByUserName}}</td>
                                <td style="text-align:center">{{completionInfo.dteDateSSQLastUpdated}}</td>
                                <td style="text-align:center">{{ssqdetails.vchLastCompleteQuarter}}</td>
                                <td style="text-align:center">{{ssqdetails.intAvgNumEmployees}}</td>
                                <td style="text-align:center">{{ssqdetails.ActiveInstructorCount}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="background-color:#cfe7f1">
                                <td colspan="5">
                                    Reason of Status:&nbsp;{{completionInfo.IncompleteReason}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat="info in incompleteInfo">
                                <td style="text-decoration:underline;color:blue;text-align:left;cursor:pointer" ng-value="info.QuestionSectionID" ng-click="viewIncomplete(info.QuestionSectionID)">View</td>
                                <td colspan="4">{{info.vchSectionName}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Questionnaire">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table style="width:100%; border:dotted 1px">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color:#003a5d; color:white;font-weight:bold">
                            <th colspan="3" style="padding-left:10px">Questionnaire</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color:#cfe7f1">
                            <th style="padding-left:10px; width:60%">SSQ Section</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center; width:20%">Completion</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center; width:20%">Print Selection</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="section in sections" style="border-bottom:dotted 1px">
                            <td style="text-decoration:underline; color:blue; cursor:pointer" ng-model="section" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#stack1" ng-click="viewSection(section)">{{section.vchSectionName}}</td>
                            <td style="border-left:dotted 1px">
                                <div ng-switch="section.bitSectionCompleted">
                                    <div ng-switch-when="true">
                                        <div style="color:green; text-align:center" ng-bind-html="section.bitSectionCompleted | applyMarks | trustedhtml"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div ng-switch-when="false">
                                        <div style="color:red; text-align:center" ng-bind-html="section.bitSectionCompleted | applyMarks | trustedhtml"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:center; border-left:dotted 1px"><input type="checkbox" checklist-model="getSections()" checklist-value="section" ng-change="printSelection(section, checked)" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <br />
                <div cg-busy="loadingSections">@*  *@</div>
                <div class="float-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="width:200px" ng-click="selectAll()">Select All</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="width:200px" ng-click="unselectAll()">Unselect All</button></div><br /><br />
                <div class="float-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:200px" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#stack4" ng-disabled="dataLoading" ng-click="printSections()">Print 

Selected</button></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
```

I tried using the the double colon operator but that didn't help.  I'm confused as to what I need to change or how to change this to make it idempotent.  The service makes a call to our web api (which it is calling about 4 times).  It brings back a lot of data so having it execute so many times is dragging down my application to a crawl.  Any assistance on how to improve this code is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an instance of your controller at the outer level of the app, but you are also creating additional instances inside an `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="m in majors">
        <div ng-controller="LWSCtrl">
```

This means a fresh controller is created for every occurence of `m` and any time the value of majors changes you will have more controllers created and/or destroyed.

This is probably not what you intended, I would have thought one instance of the controller would be sufficient.

Comment: That makes sense.  I added the controllers because without them, the accordions in the ng-repeat did not work separately.  I guess I should try to find another way to get the accordions to work independently.  The separate controller instances was all I could think of to solve that issue.  Thanks so much for your help.  This was baffling me.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff you might indeed want separate controllers to handle the accordians, but in that case do a different controller that just does an accordian. Or you might just want a few methods in your main controller and pass in `m` or `$index` from the repeat.